# Excel Pivot: pivot two columns in table without summarizing values

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, pivot

I'm using this query in excel for the following table:

```
SELECT 
"WORK_CENTER"."EQNO",
"UD_DATA"."UD_COLS_ID",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER1",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER2",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER3",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER4", 
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER5",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER1",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER2",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER3",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER4",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER5",
"UD_DATA"."CUSER"
FROM   "IQMS"."UD_DATA" "UD_DATA" 
FULL OUTER JOIN "IQMS"."WORK_CENTER" "WORK_CENTER" 
ON
 "UD_DATA"."PARENT_ID"="WORK_CENTER"."ID"
WHERE  
 "WORK_CENTER"."MFG_TYPE"='INJECTION'  
AND
 "UD_DATA"."UD_COLS_ID" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "WORK_CENTER"."EQNO"
```

> Result

And I get the following table:
[image: Table]

Which has duplicates apart from UD_COLS_ID(16,17,16,17...) and CUSER(1000,test1,2000,test2.....)

> Desired Result

But what I've been trying to do in Excel is pivot the column UD_COLS_ID on the CUSER(The last column in the previous image) column, remove the now duplicate lines and get [image: this.]

I've tried using excels pivot table to do this but I can't seem to prevent it from summarizing the values e.g I have UD_COLS_ID for the column headings, EQNO and CUSER as values. But it keeps summarizing the value field and there doesn't seem to be a way to not choose that? [image]

Searching for fixes for this keeps leading me back to examples where they want to summarize the data. And adding more values to the row and columns just makes it harder to follow.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You're using full outer join, but then you state a lines in the where clause that reduce this to INNER join. Do you need Full Outer Join? Do you know what it is/understand the implications of using it? I'm not saying it's causing this problem, but essentially your compliant is you're getting unexpected duplicate rows and trying to squish them after the fact, but the problem is more likely the query has been constructed incorrectly. Excel PIVOT will always want to know WHAT to do with the rows it is squishing, because it's meant for summarising, hence it needs an AVERAGE, SUM, MAX etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something more like this:

```
SELECT 
  WORK_CENTER.EQNO,
  WORK_CENTER.CUSER1,
  WORK_CENTER.CUSER2,
  WORK_CENTER.CUSER3,
  WORK_CENTER.CUSER4, 
  WORK_CENTER.CUSER5,
  WORK_CENTER.NUSER1,
  WORK_CENTER.NUSER2,
  WORK_CENTER.NUSER3,
  WORK_CENTER.NUSER4,
  WORK_CENTER.NUSER5,
  UD_DATA_id_16.CUSER as ID_16,
  UD_DATA_id_17.CUSER as ID_17

FROM   
  IQMS.WORK_CENTER WORK_CENTER 
  INNER JOIN
  IQMS.UD_DATA UD_DATA_id_16  
  ON
    WORK_CENTER.ID=UD_DATA_id_16.PARENT_ID AND
    UD_DATA_id_16.UD_COLS_ID = 16

  INNER JOIN
  IQMS.UD_DATA UD_DATA_id_17  
  ON
    WORK_CENTER.ID=UD_DATA_id_17.PARENT_ID AND
    UD_DATA_id_17.UD_COLS_ID = 17

WHERE  
  WORK_CENTER.MFG_TYPE='INJECTION'
ORDER BY 
  WORK_CENTER.EQNO
```

Why? Well, clearly UD_DATA has 2 rows per every work_center row, but you don't want both those rows each associating with every work_center row because that will double up the work_center rows. This is called a cartesian product. It gets worse if there are X rows in work_center for Y rows in ud_data, the number of duplicates becomes X * Y

What you need to do is convert the multiple rows per "thing" in ud_data into single rows. You either do this by pivoting the data in oracle, or you do it by joining the table multiple times, and specifying something that reduces the relationship to 1:1 between ud_data and work_center.

A work_center row with simplified column layout:

```
id, ud_data_id
wc1, ud1
wc2, ud2
wc3, ud3
```

A ud_data row set:

```
id, thing, otherthing
ud1, apple, 100
ud1, android, 101
ud2, apple, hello
ud2, android, goodbye
ud3, apple, jan-17
ud3, android, dec-25
```

The two UD rows per work centre row need to become one row. You either do this before you join once, by pivoting the UD data rows to look like this:

```
id, applething, androidthing
ud1, 100, 101
ud2, hello, goodbye
ud3, jan-17, dec25
```

or you join twice, selecting only what youre interested in each time (not syntactically correct with regard to ID - no db will accept this, but that's not the point being made):

```
work_center
join ud_data on id=id   AND ud_data.thing='apple'
join ud_data on id=id   AND ud_data.thing='android'
```

Comment: Thanks @Caius-Jard! I don't really fully understand the differences at times using the different joins. But again thanks for the response. I just tried and I think just the last comma before the FROM clause needs to be removed

Comment: Excel seems to be complaining about ORA-00904:"UD_DATA"."UD_COLS_ID": invalid identifier
. I'll keep looking into it as this brings me a lot closer than I have been in a while

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that! I'd joined the table in twice, calling the variants UD_DATA_id_16 / 17 as aliases (so there was no longer any table aliased as UD_DATA in the query) but left a few places where UD_DATA was referenced as a table name

Comment: No problem. And thanks for the explanation! It really helps!